# Faking atomicity for BOOL properties -> & why there is no synchronization in the sample code for NSOperation::isFinished,isExecuting?

Tags: objective-c, optimization, concurrency, synchronization, memory-access

Can I get away with this or compiler would essentially optimise the BOOL atomics about the same way on my behalf?

```
@interface IDBWebpValidationOperation()

// I suppose I could get away with nonatomic properties cause I write single byte properties
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isExecuting) BOOL executing;
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isFinished) BOOL finished;

@end

@implementation IDBWebpValidationOperation

@synthesize executing = _executing;
@synthesize finished = _finished;

-(BOOL)isFinished
{
    return _finished;
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _finished = finished;
    OSMemoryBarrier();
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

-(BOOL)isExecuting
{
    return _executing;
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _executing = executing;
    OSMemoryBarrier();
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}
```

PS For these two particular properties that are not accessed too frequently
I guess such a premature optimization is useless but I wonder how this works
under the hood so the question is probably still useful (to me if not to
anyone else on s.o. ;-)

Comment: `OSMemoryBarrier()` does nothing to guarantee atomicity.  Let's say accessing a bool wasn't already atomic at the CPU level.  If the assignment was midway through, another thread could read the partially-updated value before the memory barrier was hit.

Comment: Right, for long PODs such as long longs that can be sent over the momory bus in two helpings it does not. But for single bytest that bools are how could the access could be possibly non atomic?

Comment: I don't understand.  Bools are already read and written atomically (on any CPU architecture that matters).  Adding a memory barrier doesn't help even when the assignment _isn't_ atomic.  It certainly doesn't help you when the assignment is _already_ atomic.  Basically, the memory barrier doesn't change the atomicity of the assignment at all, so it's not a valid way of implementing the `atomic` attribute of a property.

Comment: Right, but atomicity of the property also implies that as soon as you write it it becomes visible on other cpu core (by definition). Whereas if you declare property as nonatomic the behavior in multithreaded environment is not defined. Thusly I assume there must be an implementation difference between atomic and nonatomic BOOL. I also assume atomicizing BOOL is cheaper than atomicizing long long. The question is about that difference.

Comment: No, atomicity does not imply that.  Atomicity implies that no reader will see a partial write.  It says nothing about when any given write becomes visible.

Comment: By the way, I believe that adding a barrier on the _reader_ would help.  That would ensure that any writes which have just completed will be seen.  It is, however, a horrible way to do it, because a memory barrier requires waiting for _all_ updates to be posted, which can be really slow given the relative speeds of the CPU and the memory bus.

Comment: So, from implementation perspective, atomic bools == non atomic bools cause it's not possible to make an non atomic bool write except on a system with a memory bus narrower than 8 bits? which none of the ios devices are.

Comment: I guess I better make this atomic and @synchronize(self) the getter and the setter instead of guessting. It's odd (to me) that all sample code that implements the isFinished and isRunning setter is not synchronized (and nonatomic in the examples that can be found in objective-c). Maybe atomicity is irrelevant here since the stakeholders are notified through KVO?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120482/discussion-between-avi-and-anton-tropashko).